# Can't find a td node with id in XPath

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, web-crawler, lxml

[This](https://www.ntuh.gov.tw/labmed/%E6%AA%A2%E9%A9%97%E7%9B%AE%E9%8C%84/Lists/2015/BC.aspx) is the webpage which I am targeting. My problem is that I can't specify a td node with its id:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

test_url = "https://www.ntuh.gov.tw/labmed/檢驗目錄/Lists/2015/BC.aspx"
page_response = requests.get(test_url, verify=False)
page_root = html.fromstring(page_response.content)
page_root.xpath("//td[@id='pagingWPQ2next']/a/@onclick")
```

The final line yields `[]` while that node actually exists and can be found by `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@id='pagingWPQ2next']")` with `selenium`. It's the "next page" button at the bottom of the page. It can be found in the page source:

[image: td[@id='pagingWPQ2next']]

Another example is [this](http://www.ntuh.gov.tw/labmed/%E6%AA%A2%E9%A9%97%E7%9B%AE%E9%8C%84/Lists/2015/DispForm.aspx?ID=369&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Entuh%2Egov%2Etw%2Flabmed%2F%25E6%25AA%25A2%25E9%25A9%2597%25E7%259B%25AE%25E9%258C%2584%2FLists%2F2015%2FBC%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x01003E4C6DCCAFBEF64BACFA9B88DBDEF416) webpage.

```
detail_url = "http://www.ntuh.gov.tw/labmed/檢驗目錄/Lists/2015/DispForm.aspx?ID=369&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Entuh%2Egov%2Etw%2Flabmed%2F%25E6%25AA%25A2%25E9%25A9%2597%25E7%259B%25AE%25E9%258C%2584%2FLists%2F2015%2FBC%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x01003E4C6DCCAFBEF64BACFA9B88DBDEF416"
page_response = requests.get(detail_url, verify=False)
page_root = html.fromstring(page_response.content)
page_root.xpath("//td[@id='_7']/table/tr")
# This line yields []
page_root.xpath("//table[@id='onetIDListForm']/tr/td/div/div/div/div/table/tr[3]/td/table/tr")
# This line gives me trs as expected
# However I thought both lines should work
```

Again, the similar problem: I cannot specify the td node with its id, but I can specify a table with id and find the very same td downstream. This element can also be found in the source code:

[image: td[@id='_7']/table/tr]

Why is that and how am I supposed to find it correctly? Thanks.

Comment: Does the browser navigate successfully to the Chinese URL?

Comment: Pagination block is not present in page source, but generated dynamically, so `requests` + `lxml` will not return you the output you want.

Comment: @GalAbra Yes it does.

Comment: @Andersson Thank you. Would you please take a look at my additional example in edits as well? I don't think this one is a pagination block but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @ytu , do right click on browser page and then click on "View Page Source". There you can search for required elements. If its not available on Page Source then it's dynamic, otherwise, you can grab it simply with `requests` + `lxml`

Comment: @Andersson All my provided examples are available on Page Source and I can literally see them. It's just not reachable by XPath, which is strange to me. Especially in the second example, `//table[@id='onetIDListForm']/tr/td/div/div/div/div/table/tr[3]/td/table/tr` suggests that those tr nodes cab be grabbed with `requests` + `lxml`. I think those grabbed tr nodes then should also be grabbed with `//td[@id='_7']/table/tr`, but apparently somehow it's not the case. I don't know why.

Comment: I have opened the source code of your first website sample (`view-source:https://www.ntuh.gov.tw/labmed/%E6%AA%A2%E9%A9%97%E7%9B%AE%E9%8C%84/Lists/2015/BC.aspx`) and `pagingWPQ2next` does not exist there.

Comment: @Tomalak That's weird. Am I misunderstanding something? 'Cause I can see it just right there. Please see my screenshots provided above in edits.

Comment: You look at the visual representation of the DOM. That's not the source code.

Comment: For web pages with dynamic content, you will get better results with Selenium (https://www.seleniumhq.org/) or Headless Chrome (https://duo.com/decipher/driving-headless-chrome-with-python).